# How to get array values from Eloquent pluck method

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a table with two columns, X and Y and data something like:

```
X   Y
1   1
1   2
1   3
1   4
2   5
2   6
```

And when I do something like `->pluck('Y', 'X')` I want an answer like:

```
['1' => [1,2,3,4], '2' => [5,6]]
```

But instead it just gives me one value instead of an array like

```
['1' => 1, '2' => '5']
```

How can I make the values an array?

Answer (score 2):

Using [reduce](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-reduce)

```
$collection->reduce(function ($carry, $item) {
    // First iteration
    if ($carry == null) {
        $carry = [];
    }

    $carry[$item->X][] = $item->Y;
    return $carry;
});
```

Using [groupBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-groupby):

```
$collection->groupBy('X')->map(function ($item) {
    return $item->pluck('Y');
})->toArray()
```

Using [mapToGroups](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-maptogroups)

```
$collection->mapToGroups(function ($item) {
    return [$item['X'] => $item['Y']];
})->toArray()
```

Comment: That's closer than I've gotten before!  Right now the groupBy method you suggested returns `[1 => [["X": "1", "Y": "1"], ["X": "1", "Y": "2"], ["X": "1", "Y": "3"]...`  so now it's too many arrays.

Comment: The reduce method give the right answer.  Do you think there's a solution that works using the groupBy or should I just stick with reduce?

Comment: I will update the answer and fix the issue with `groupBy`

Comment: Thanks for the updates!  If all three methods work, is there any reason to choose one over another?

Comment: One thing I noticed, which is a low priority, but would be nice if it could be fixed, is that it changes the order of the values in the Y column to be sorted.  In my example data above, they were already sorted, but if they were in a different order, with the above methods, they always come out sorted.  I tried all three with the same result.